# Filtering languages queryset looping on tuple (code, name_translated)

Tags: python, django, filter

I need to filter a queryset based on language field (language code) from an input. For example in italian, a user might search for 'italian'. So the first thing I've done is created a list of tuple containing (lang_code, name_translated) as following:

```py
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES
from django.utils.translation import get_language_info

# List of tuples (code, translated_name)
TRANSLATED_LANGUAGES = [(l[0], get_language_info(l[0])['name_translated']) for l in LANGUAGES]
```

Here is the method for filtering:

```py
def filter_by_languages(self, queryset, name, value):
    for l in TRANSLATED_LANGUAGES:
        if value in l[1].lower():
            queryset.filter(Q(lang_src__code__iexact=l[0]))
    return queryset.distinct()
```

It returns a queryset which is not filtered. I must misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the queryset incorrectly. Here is the solution:

```py
def filter_by_languages(self, queryset, name, value):
    search = []
    for l in TRANSLATED_LANGUAGES:
        if value in l[1].lower():
            search.append(l[0])
    return queryset.filter(lang_src__code__in=search)
```